# Convert string to actual UTF-8 character

Tags: ruby, utf-8

the sample file contains this.
`[&quot; \u042D\u0440\u044B\u0433\u044D\u0436\u044D\u044D. \n&quot;]`

I want to replace `\u[a-zA-Z0-9]` chars with actual utf-8 character.
What should be done?

```
File.new("mnosis.xml").each_line do |line|
  re = /\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/
  new_str = line.gsub(re) {|match| puts match[0..1] + '#{' + match[2..5] + '}' }
  puts new_str
end
```

Comment: What version of ruby do you use? Do you mean that file contains text \u042D\u0440\u044B\u0433\u044D\u0436\u044D\u044D or actually file contains text Эрыгэжээ. ?

Comment: the file contains strings like \u042D\u... etc. Not an actual character

Answer (score 5):

```
new_str = line.gsub(re) {|match| Array(match[2..5].to_i(16)).pack('U') }
=> "Эрыгэжээ."
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\u` characters are real UTF-8 characters. The `\u` is a way of expressing them in a way that they can be used in non-UTF-8 editors. Ruby sees the `\u` and the actual character character the same.

Answer (score 1):

[eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) can do the trick:

```
ruby-1.9.2 > str = '\u042D\u0440\u044B\u0433\u044D\u0436\u044D\u044D.'
 => "\\u042D\\u0440\\u044B\\u0433\\u044D\\u0436\\u044D\\u044D." 
ruby-1.9.2 > str_to_eval = "\"#{str}\""
 => "\"\\u042D\\u0440\\u044B\\u0433\\u044D\\u0436\\u044D\\u044D.\"" 
ruby-1.9.2 > res = eval(str_to_eval)
 => "Эрыгэжээ."
```

Comment: @Tass: agree, eval may cause security risk if string is received from non-secure source